# BubbleSort - Lexicográfica (Ordem Alfabética) repete o primeiro nome

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um exercício de ordenação de nome com o BubbleSort, porém quando ordenados, o primeiro nome se repete.

Exemplo: coloco para cadastrar 5 pessoas:

> Ana
>   Luiza
>   Gabriel
>   Ester
>   Luciana

E a ordenação sai da seguinte forma:

> Ana
>   Ana
>   Ester
>   Gabriel
>   Luciana

Alguém saberia me explicar porque isso acontece?

Aqui está meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

//Função do Bubble Sort
void bubbleSort(char (*V)[30], int Fim)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
    int i, j;
    char temp[30];

    for(i=1; i<Fim; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<Fim; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(V[j], V[j+1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, V[j]);
                strcpy(V[j], V[j+1]);
                strcpy(V[j+1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Código
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
    int Fim=0, i=0;

    printf("\n Quantas pessoas deseja cadastrar? ");
    scanf("%i", &Fim);
    char V[Fim][30];

    for(i=0; i<Fim; i++)
    {
        printf("\n ---------------------------------------");
        printf("\n   Digite o nome da %iº pessoa: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", &V[i]);
    }
    system("cls");


    printf("\n ############### ORDENAÇÃO POR NOME ###############");
    for(i=0; i<Fim; i++)
    {
        bubbleSort(V, Fim);
        printf("\n %s", V[i]);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Não e necessário saudações e cumprimentos aqui, recomendo que dê uma lida em **[tour]** para entender como funciona o site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ficar correto no seu código faça da seguinte forma:

```
void bubbleSort(char (*V)[30], int Fim)
{
    int i, j;
    char temp[30];
 
    for(i=0; i<Fim; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<Fim - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(V[j], V[j+1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, V[j]);
                strcpy(V[j], V[j+1]);
                strcpy(V[j+1], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O motivo pelo qual não estava a sair como pretende é que a sua lógica do `bubble sort` não está correta em alguns pormenores:

- A leitura dos nomes com `%s` tem um `&` a mais pois numa string, a própria string funciona já como se fosse um ponteiro logo não é suposto levar o `&`, aqui:

  ```
    for(i=0; i<Fim; i++)
    {
         printf("\n ---------------------------------------");
         printf("\n   Digite o nome da %iº pessoa: ", i+1);
         scanf("%s", &V[i]);
         //          ^--- está a mais
  ```
- O primeiro `for` do bubble sort é suposto começar em `0` e não `1`:

  ```
    for(i=1; i<Fim; i++)
    //    ^--- 0 em vez de 1
  ```
- O fim do segundo `for` também não está correto, e inclusivamente sai fora do array, o que basicamente gera comportamento indefinido:

  ```
    for(i=1; i<Fim; i++)
        for(j=0; j<Fim; j++)
        //          ^--- este
  ```

  Se está a trocar com `j+1`, ou seja com o elemento da frente através de `strcpy(V[j], V[j+1]);` então quando estiver no ultimo, o próximo já está fora do array o que está incorreto. Na verdade devido aos elementos que já ficaram corretamente posicionados precisa apenas de ir até ao fim menos os que o `i` já andou.

  Correto seria :

  ```
    for(j=0; j<Fim-1-i; j++)
    //         ^^^^^^^
  ```

[Veja no Ideone a funcionar](https://ideone.com/r3HdO0)

Algumas notas relevantes:

- Chame apenas um `setlocale` uma vez e preferencialmente no inicio do `main`. Neste momento está a chamar dentro da função do `bubbleSort` que não faz sentido, apesar de não lhe causar nenhum erro.
- Evite incluir bibliotecas que não está a utilizar como o `time.h` ou `math.h`
- Evite capitalizar os nomes de variáveis, uma vez que isso foge claramente do padrão de nomenclatura que se usa em C.

Comment: Funcionou! Só mais uma pergunta: O que é capitalizar nomes de variáveis?

Comment: @Luizous Capitalizar é colocar nomes de variáveis com a primeira letra em maiuscula, como por exemplo `Fim` que devia ser `fim`.